# SQL Server - Pivoting rows into fixed number of columns with columns sorted rather than rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL server 2012 and I am trying to 'pivot' a table output so that I can reformat a results table for display to the user.
The easiest way to describe it is with an example:

Input

```
MyCol
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
```

Output

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1       7       13
2       8       14
3       9       15
4       10      16
5       11      17
6       12
```

I thought about using temporary tables to store the relevant row values and then query those but it seems a little long winded. There has to be a slick way to achieve this beyond my expertise.

Comment: How you `pivot` the table ? What is the logic behind `pivot` ? Please be clear.

Comment: What happened to 1 and 2?

Comment: ...a typo happened to 1 & 2

Comment: My use of the word 'pivot' is because I am struggling to describe it any other way.

Comment: That was the reporting job to paging and formating like that, Of course you can implement that query output with dynamic SQL but it is a waste of time.

Comment: I fully agree that normally this would be the job of the presentation layer, but this is part of a much larger parameter driven retrieval function and as such if I can do the formatting as well then I can simplify the presentation layer and keep everything in one place. From a maintenance point of view, six extra lines of SQL are better than a rats nest at the other end. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions to enumerate and count the rows and then some arithmetic to assign the position:

```
select (case when mycol < ceil(cnt / 3) then mycol end) as col1,
       (case when mycol >= ceil(cnt / 3) and mycol < 2*ceil(cnt / 3) then mycol end) as col2,
       (case when mycol >= 2*ceil(cnt / 3) then mycol end) as col3       
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by mycol) - 1 as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
group by mycol % ceil(cnt / 3)
```